# How to host multiple Endpoints on a single ServiceStack instance

Tags: c#, servicestack

I've got the scenario where I need to host two APIs on a single website. One is a public API for JavaScript calls etc which is developed by a third party (so not editable), the other is a private API which has authentication etc.

The public API automatically looks for the service it includes and wires those but and (correctly) ignores the private services.

The problem I have however is I can't see any way of adding another endpoint (Googling around suggests the app_host is a singleton which is the root of the issue).

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) was designed to support a single AppHost which we discuss in this [related issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/609).

So it doesn't support multiple HttpListeners in the same AppDomain. You could use a reverse proxy or potentially you could manually load multiple instances of ServiceStack in different AppDomains.

Comment: I see, how would you recommend accommodating a public and private API if you weren't able to spin up different AppDomains?

Comment: @Tim Use the built-in [Security Access Restrictions?](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Security)